# Build pairs from an ordered list

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm playing with train time tables and considering building connections between stations from the times.

Let's take an example:

```
Trip I:  A (t1) ------------> B (t3) ------------> E (t5)
Trip II:          C (t2) ------------> D (t4) ---> E (t6)
```

We have 5 stops (`A` to `E`) where trains stop at time `ti` with two different trips (from `A` to `E` through `B` and from `C to`E`though`D`).

Time table looks like this (on a database point of view, there is also a technical identifier):

```
 --------------------
| Trip | Stop | Time |
 --------------------
| I    | A    | t1   |
| I    | B    | t3   |
| I    | E    | t5   |
| II   | C    | t2   |
| II   | D    | t4   | 
| II   | E    | t6   | 
 --------------------
```

I'd like to build from this the connections between stations, something like (let's not take into account the time the trains spends in the station stopped for simplicity):

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| Departure stop | Departure time | Arrival stop | Arrival time |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| A              | t1             | B            | t3           |
| B              | t3             | E            | t5           |
| C              | t2             | D            | t4           |
| D              | t4             | E            | t6           |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I already did it in memory with some code:

1. grouping by trip,
2. sorting by time,
3. taking elements 2-by-2 in a sliding window.

However, it is simple but not very efficient.

That's why I'm wondering if it can be expressed using SQL. 
Does it?

How would you do?

I'm using PostgreSQL for my tests but I am more interested in the outlines than the exact implementation for a specific database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st I'd generate a rownumber for each trip partition and then self join on the row_number + 1=row_number

Each row for each trip, the engine will be assigned a number 1-N in the order of time ascending.   This allows us to simply self join on the row_number + 1.

Where this may be a problem is if time is JUST time and you have a departure at 2300 and an arrival at 0100 or if the trip spans days. I'm also assuming militarily time here.  If it's 11:00 and 1:00 then we might have problems as well.

Since each numbering will restart at 1, so we need to join on the trip as well.

```
WITH CTE As (
SELECT A.*, row_Number() over (partition by trip Order by time asc) RN FROM TIME A)

SELECT A.Stop, A.Time, B.Stop, B.Time
FROM CTE A 
INNER JOIN CTE B 
  on A.RN+1 = B.RN
 and A.trip = B.Trip
```

Comment: No problem for time spanning: times are stored as seconds since midnight (so a train arriving the next day at 01:00 will be seen as a train arriving on the same same day at "25:00").

Comment: the CTE isn't 100% necessary, but I think it's cleaner than having to generate the result set twice (once for each use of CTE)  and if we didn't partition by trip, then we wouldn't need to join on trip as each row would have it's own time, but we would need to order by trip then time.

Comment: Thanks! I have to debug a little my dataset but it seems it builds trips in only one way: with A <--> B <--> C, I get A-->B and B-->C but not C-->B and B-->A. I might have missed something.

Comment: C-->B would have a different start time right and represent a different trip,right?  I'd need to see sample data where you show C-->B and B-->A

Comment: There should be, yes: the query seems fine to me. That's why I believed I missed something. 
If you want to play, the dataset is here: https://data.ratp.fr/explore/dataset/offre-transport-de-la-ratp-format-gtfs/ (and my sandbox to feed the db is there: https://github.com/adericbourg/shortest-path-sandbox/tree/master/src/main/scala/net/dericbourg/ratp/gtfs )

Comment: Alright, I can confirm that it's alright. Using GTFS, stops don't have the same identifier in one way and the other.